# Taking average of indexes in 2d matrix without using numpy

Tags: python, matrix, average, nested-lists

I want to take the average of my 2d matrix using for loops. However, I'm struggling with taking the total length of the 2d matrix. This is what i've got so far:

[image link to my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpP6e.png)

I don't know where i am going wrong, as the average of this matrix should be 5.0 but it returns 7.5

Comment: Don't post images of code. Paste the formatted code into the question.

Comment: I'm a new user so it told me i need to get 10 reputation points or something to post embedded code.

Comment: @Pickamon. Use the edit button under the questions to place your code in.

Comment: @Pickamon - I think you may have misunderstood that. You don't need to embed anything, just paste the code into your question (you can use the edit button). If you indent it all four spaces (or select it all and hit command-k) it will format it.

Comment: Oh ok, Thank you! @MarkMeyer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over all rows and columns, summing all the values and counting the number of entries. This can then be used to calculate a mean

```
total = 0
entries = 0
for row in matrix:
    for value in row:
        total += value
        entries += 1
mean = total / entries
```

Comment: You can use sum and len effectively here

Comment: @MadPhysicist true but I feel like we should start with the basics with people sometimes